# Object cron_jobs does not exist (15)

Tags: php, symfony1

I am new in symfony and github.

**Question:** When I delete a job having id 15, it display this error message. "Object cron_jobs does not exist (15)".
Bellow is my code.

```
$this->forward404Unless($cron_jobs = CronJobsPeer::retrieveByPk($request->getParameter('id')), sprintf('Object cron_jobs does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('id')));
        $cron_jobs->delete();
```

Comment: which version of symfony you are using? symfony 1.4? Can you clarify what problem do you have?

Comment: I am using symfony 1.2.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cron_jobs object with the id 15 doesn't exist, forward404Unless() should forward the user (you) to a 404 page, which is exactly what the forward404Unless() method does.
If *$message* from *forward404Unless ($condition, $message = null)* is not null, you can use it on the 404 page to display what the problem is.
Maybe you have deleted the cron_jobs object with the id 15 twice and thats why you get the 404 page shown.

> If you really use version 1.2.12 you should upgrade as soon as
>   possible because this version of symfony is not maintained anymore.